# Decrypt a PlayReady encrypted smooth streaming content (PIFF 1.3)

Tags: video-streaming, cloud, drm, azure-media-services, playready

I am looking for a tool to decrypt a PlayReady encrypted Smooth Streaming content(with PIFF 1.3) into a clear smooth streaming asset. I have the encryption key and IV. Is there any tool recommendations or open source project I could run?

Thanks,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: There was a few years ago (2011 or so) a utility called PIFFEncryptor which Microsoft distributed to their IIS Media Services TAP adopters. The utility came with full C# sources. If I recall correctly, one of that tool's command-line options was to *decrypt* PIFF files, or at least to verify that encryption was successful.

Am not aware of any commercial or FOSS tool that can do the same though.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I am checking my team for this PIFFEncryptor tool.

Comment: If you have a key and IV already you could do it yourselves. PIFF tells you how encrypted data are stored so you just need to pick samples or sub-samples from the stream and correctly chain them - after that it is just AES decryption.